How to assign weights for my model to avoid weird mesh deformation?
I made a 3D model of player for my Unity game. In Unity some animations looks terrifying an recently i noticed that it also looks bad in Blender. I know how to use Weight Paint mode but i don't know how to achieve right result with it (to fix weird deformations).
This is a screenshot of animation in which my character bends down to strike with his sword. In Unity it looks even worse.


It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.
